# Python get pandas data per column name

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to extract data per pandas by column named 'model'.
The below code does work, but how do I write the code if I want to use x = R1200GS (without '')?

As I need to pass this var from other function, let me know if there is a good way.
Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_database(z):
    df=pd.read_csv("database.csv")
    df=df.query("model==@z")
    return df

x = 'R1200GS'

get_database(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, so will post here. Not sure this will ever work. `x = R1200GS` will throw an error unless there's an object named `R1200GS`.

Just curious: what is the issue with using a string? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: class ScatterView(TemplateView) :
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs) :
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = SampleForm(request.GET) 
        z = request.GET.get('input_model_name')
        context['data'] = plots.get_data(z)
        return render(request, 'simulator.html', context)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Here, I want to use the web form input by GET method as above code, then utilize the input data (model) to extract the data.

Comment: pls see my comments